# Android MapView with GoogleTileOverlay not freeing bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, android-mapview, osmdroid

I am having an issue with drawing custom tiles over Google maps.

Using [GoogleTileOverlay](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-google-overlay/src/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/GoogleTilesOverlay.java?r=921) from `OSMDroid`, I am drawing custom tiles that are stored locally on the devices SD card.

The problem occurs after I have opened the map and then try to return to other activities.  Things start getting weird.  Background colors defined in XML aren't showing up and other strange things.

I have searched far and wide for a reason and all I have been able to come up with is that there is not enough memory?

[According to Eclipse MAT](http://pastebin.com/yPVcjMAg) there is 8.4 MB of bitmaps left over *after* I have destroyed the activity that holds the `MapView` and `GoogleTileOverlay`

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Comment: Same problem here. I've tried to clear the tiles cache onPause of Google maps activity but it seems some bitmaps still remains holding on the activity reference thus not being GCed after the activity is destroyed.. Any insights to your situation so far?

Comment: @plesatejvlk Unfortunately, No.  I have resorted to forcing the app to completely restart itself once the activity is finished.  I was having some seriously weird issues with colors on my XML resources.  Still looking for a better solution, but for now, it works.

Comment: In MAT, did you see single instance of your map activity after few activity switches (in your original solution)? Particularly the LRUMapTileCache? In my case it was the cache holding on the bitmaps (referring back to the activity) which was leaking the whole activity resulting in OOM in the end. I solved it with removing overlay from MapView's overlays list _before_ I called clearMapTiles on provider and it solved the leaks. But still having the 8 MB in memory, at least only once.

Comment: Also, did you try adding android:largeHeap="true" to the application tag in manifest? This should alloc more memory (in my case close to 100 MB), see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dealing with OOM exceptions due to memory leaks coming from the bitmaps. It seems that removing the overlay from `MapView`'s `Overlay` list before clearing the tiles cache (so that no new tiles are created after the clearance) in `onPause` of map activity works. I ended up having single instance of `LRUMapTileCache` no matter how many times the map activity was created / resumed.

My `onPause` batch is as follows:

```
// .. get custom tiles off the screen first
mMapView.getOverlays().remove(mCustomTilesOverlay);         
// .. release all custom tiles' bitmaps
mCustomTilesOverlay.clearTileCache();
// .. unregister intent receiver (in order not to leak it)
mCustomTilesOverlay.detach();
// .. indicate not-ready state by clearing the reference
mCustomTilesOverlay = null;
```

<strike>The 8 MB still persist though</strike> (see edit), I'm using the `android:largeHeap="true"` application attribute to compensate.

**edit**

Turned out those 8 MB came from other sources. The cache gets successfuly cleared with this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Does the `onPause` code still leave the memory leak?  If so, what does it accomplish?  `android:largeHeap` may be an option.  I'll give that a shot next time I get a chance.

Comment: Awesome, I will give it a shot next time I have a chance and report back.